# Average of percentage

Tags: statistics, percentages

I know I can't average the % change but I'm having trouble coming up with weights for these numbers
Here's [Image Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4ed2KN_-UoAWU5iYjNEMkhIcWc/view?usp=sharing) .

Each combined row represents a group and the bottom rows are adding up R and P basically.
I'm wondering how you can end up with 35.2 if you have 33, 21 and 21.7.
I can't come up with weights. Is there a solution to this?
Also the percentage is calculated using the following logic:

(8.36/6.29)-1=33.03 (13.04/10.71)-1=21.72 and so on so we get 33.03 21.72 and 21.78

Comment: Your link seems to be broken to me.

Comment: How are those percentages being computed?

Comment: (8.36/6.29)-1=33.03  (13.04/10.71)-1=21.72 and so on so we get 33.03 21.72 and 21.78 but the overall percentage is 35.24

Comment: I can't inline images either, strangely; imgur is blocking the requests.

Comment: @BardiyaChoupani: That process is not obvious and should be added to the post for clarification.

Comment: I changed the image to a link and added some more info regarding where the % coming from. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, we have, for $i = 1, 2, 3$:

- Two input values $P_{1,i}$ and $P_{2,i}$
- Two input values $R_{1,i}$ and $R_{2,i}$
- Two derived values $Q_{1,i} = \frac{R_{1,i}}{P_{1,i}}$ and $Q_{2,i} = \frac{R_{2,i}}{P_{2,i}}$
- One proportional increase $F_i = \frac{Q_{2,i}-Q_{1,i}}{Q_{1,i}}$

At the bottom, we also have

- $\sum P_{i,1}$ and $\sum P_{i,2}$
- $\sum R_{i,1}$ and $\sum R_{i,2}$
- Two derived values $Q_1 = \frac{\sum R_{1,i}}{\sum P_{1,i}}$ and $Q_2 = \frac{\sum R_{2,i}}{\sum P_{2,i}}$
- One proportional increase $F = \frac{Q_2-Q_1}{Q_1}$

There is no particular reason to think that $F$ is any kind of weighted mean of the $F_i$.  This is, I think, basically a variation of [Simpson's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_paradox).

---

Here's a simpler example with only two rows that illustrates the issue:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
P & R & R/P & \text{percent difference} \\ \hline
5 & 20 & 4 & \\
6 & 30 & 5 & \frac{5-4}{4} = 25\% \\ \hline
1 & 10 & 10 & \\
10 & 130 & 13 & \frac{13-10}{10} = 30\% \\ \hline
5+1 = 6 & 20+10 = 30 & 5 & \\
6+10 = 16 & 30+130 = 160 & 10 & \frac{10-5}{5} = 100\% \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

The seeming "paradox" in this example arises from a few properties of the data:

- The first set of data has smaller ratios and its scale barely increases, staying at medium size.
- The second set of data has larger ratios and its scale increases dramatically from very small to very large.
- When we sum the data, the ratio of the first row is dominated by the first set of data, whose ratio is smaller; the ratio of the second row is dominated by the second set of data, whose ratio is larger.  Therefore, the increase in ratio is higher than the corresponding increase in either set of data in isolation.

In your data, the first set of data has smaller ratios and a modest increase in scale, whereas the other two sets of data have larger ratios and more dramatic increases in scale.  It's less stark than in the example I constructed, but that's more or less what's happening.

Comment: This makes 100% sense to me. However, does it make sense to have a larger percentage of the total values when each group % of change is less? Intuitively it doesn't make sense to me to have 33%, 21.7%, and 21.78% and the final average is 35.2%.

Comment: @BardiyaChoupani: I'll try to come up with a simpler example that uses rounder numbers to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @BardiyaChoupani: I hope the example makes the situation clearer.